# XPath for "text matches one of the following strings"?

Tags: regex, xpath

I'm writing an automated test for a page where the contents are partially randomized: the text of an element will be one of a known set of possibilities.

I want to write an XPath selector that says: "there's an `<h3>` whose contents are either `Foo` or `Bar` or `Baz`".

**How would I do that?**

I think I need a regular expression and `matches`. I've tried `//h3[matches(text(), 'Foo|Bar|Baz|')]'`, but the library I'm using says that's not a valid query. (I don't know what version of XPath it uses.)

Comment: You should write it as `//h3[text() = 'Foo' or text() = 'Bar' or text() = 'Baz']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions and the `matches()` function require **XPath 2.0**.

If your library only supports **XPath 1.0**, then use this XPath,

```
//h3[.='Foo' or .='Bar' or .='Baz']
```

to select all `h3` elements whose string value is one of `Foo` or `Bar` or `Baz` without needing to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Using XPath 2.0 and later you can also use `//h3[. = ('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz')]` if you simply want to compare the string contents of the `h3` element to those three values in the sequence.